# Match "x out of y" fields in a document

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

I'm writing a service to handle bans for a game and I'm currently a bit stuck trying to write a MongoDB query. Currently I have a collection of "User" objects, and the objects look like this:

```cs
public class User
{
    public List<Ban> Bans { get; set; }

    // some irrelevant additional fields
}

public class Ban
{
    public HardwareId HWID { get; set; }

    public DateTime Expires { get; set; }

    // some irrelevant additional fields
}

public class HardwareId : IEquatable<HardwareId>
{
    public string Field1 { get; set; }

    public string Field2 { get; set; }

    public string Field3 { get; set; }

    public string Field4 { get; set; }

    public bool Equals([AllowNull] HardwareId other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(other, null)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;

        return Field1 == other.Field1 &&
            Field2 == other.Field2 &&
            Field3 == other.Field3 &&
            Field4 == other.Field4;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is have a query that finds all users with a ban where HWID has say 3 out of 4 fields matching. Currently I have a query that only finds users where the HWID match exactly (due to the Equals() implementation), but I'd like to change it. My current code looks like this:

```cs
public Ban FindBan(HardwareId hwid)
{
    var banBuilder = Builders<Ban>.Filter;
    var hwidFilter = banBuilder.Eq(b => b.HWID, hwid);
    var expFilter = banBuilder.Gt(b => b.Expires, DateTime.UtcNow);
    var banFilter = banBuilder.And(hwidFilter, expFilter);

    var user = _users.Find(Builders<User>.Filter.ElemMatch(p => p.Bans, banFilter)).FirstOrDefault();
    if (user != null)
    {
        return user.Bans[0];
    }

    return null;
}
```

The only way of solving it I can think of is to write "spaghetti if-statements" in the Equals() function, but I'd like a dynamic solution where I could add multiple "Fields" to the HardwareId class later down the line. Another issue with the FindBan() function currently is the fact that it returns "user.Bans[0]" instead of the actual ban that was found, but I imagine I could solve that by sorting by expiry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a method similar to Equals (or make changes to it), so that you have each condition match  in to an array

```
    FldArr[0] = (Field1 == other.Field1);
    FldArr[1] = (Field2 == other.Field2);
    FldArr[2] = (Field3 == other.Field3);
    FldArr[3] = (Field4 == other.Field4);
```

Then by using LINQ for FldArr, you can find 3/4 true conditions.

Answer (score 1):

here's one approach to match by minimum of 3 fields of HWID:

```java
var numFieldsToMatch = 3;

var hwid = {
    Field1: "one",
    Field2: "two",
    Field3: "three",
    Field4: "four"
};

db.User.find({
    $expr: {
        $anyElementTrue: {
            $map: {
                input: "$Bans",
                in: {
                    $gte: [{
                        $size: {
                            $filter: {
                                input: { $objectToArray: "$$this.HWID" },
                                cond: {
                                    $or: [
                                        { $and: [{ $eq: ["$$this.k", "Field1"] }, { $eq: ["$$this.v", hwid.Field1] }] },
                                        { $and: [{ $eq: ["$$this.k", "Field2"] }, { $eq: ["$$this.v", hwid.Field2] }] },
                                        { $and: [{ $eq: ["$$this.k", "Field3"] }, { $eq: ["$$this.v", hwid.Field3] }] },
                                        { $and: [{ $eq: ["$$this.k", "Field4"] }, { $eq: ["$$this.v", hwid.Field4] }] }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }, numFieldsToMatch]
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/MPwB14o6kuO

it's not possible to translate this mongo query to c# driver code afaik.
see [here](https://dev.to/djnitehawk/overcoming-the-limitations-of-mongodb-c-driver-1110) for an easy way to run this with c#.